# Better way to version control of files from PHP programs

Tags: php, git, symfony, svn, version-control

I have been create a file system in PHP (Symfony2).
(It could upload and download.)

I would like to add version control of files.
(handling version control from php programming)

I want to know what a better way to version control of files.

---

> 1 : copy file

I think a simple way of version control of files that a file is to copy as a backup file if a file with same name has been uploaded.

.

> 2 : libgit2/php-git

I am a git user. So, I thought that 'libgit2/php-git' is good way.
However, it is in the alpha version, and it seems as if they are not also updated.

.

> 3 : execute git command in PHP

```
ex.)  
    exec("git add .; git commit -m 'xxxx'");
    $log = exec("git log");
    etc...
```

.

> 4 : SVN function (PHP bindings)

I have never used, but this is sound good?

---

Please taught if there is a good way to version control in PHP.
(The better way to version control of files from PHP programs.)

Comment: Any of the options you mentioned might work well for you.  If you backup, you can take snapshots of your project and archive it somewhere.  For a small enough project, this might scale.  If things get out of hand, I would recommend Git.

Comment: You can use either SVN or GIT. which tool are you using for GIT? Bitbucket or GitHub?